# Blazor EditForm: How to handle empty values same as undefined

Tags: c#, html, blazor, webassembly

I am using an EditForm component with validations in Blazor WASM app.
The problem I have is that if I enter an input to InputText and then later decide remove it, the form acts as if I entered empty value. The consequences are either

1. The field turns red since the value is invalid due to constraints such as [MinLength]
2. The field turns green if there is no constraint on length

I would like it to act the same as if the input was never entered. So, basically, skip the validation. In ideal world, I would also like to have null instead of empty string in the bind model, but that is not as critical, since I can arrange that in submit action.

Any ideas how to simply achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make a custom validator. The Microsoft docs provide a decent guide for this. I ran into the same issue in a Blazor Server app form I'm working on. Below is the custom validator I used in addition to the StringLength attribute in model class. If you enter something into the text field, and then remove it (like you described) it will trigger the error message.

```
    public class CustomValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string GetErrorMessage() => "Invalid Text";

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        if (value == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

***** Model property annotation *****

```
[CustomValidator]
public string Text { get; set; }
```